# JQuery: OnClick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

A part of my table looks somewhat like this:

```
<td data-item="Tier1">
     <a class="infolnk" href="#">DRAFT</a>
</td>
<td data-item="Tier2">
     <a class="deletelnk" href="#"></a>
     <a class="editlnk" href="#"></a>
     <a class="infolnk" href="#">DRAFT</a>
</td>
<td data-item="Tier3">
     <a class="deletelnk" href="#"></a>
     <a class="editlnk" href="#"></a>
     <a class="infolnk" href="#">DRAFT</a>
</td>
```

To handle the `on-click -events`, i've written the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     Console.log("loading Tiers");
     LoadTiers();
     Console.log("Tiers have been loaded, loading Eventhandlers");
     SetTableEventHandlers();
}


function SetTableEventHandlers() {

    $(".deletelnk").click(function ()
    { _delete($(this)); });

    $(".infolnk").click(function ()
    { _getInfo($(this)); });
}

function _delete(lnkClicked)
{
   alert("delete clicked");
   ....
}

function _getInfo(lnkClicked)
{
   alert("Info clicked");
   ....
}
```

Yet only the `delete` seems to be working. I'm not getting any alert from _getInfo.
Can anyone see why?

**Note:** the tags with `class="deletelnk"` are declared on the html-page, `class="infolnk"` are dynamically added. Yet the setting of the event handlers occurs **after** they have been added dynamically.

Comment: Can you show where you trigger the event where you set the event handlers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: "Yet the setting of the event handlers occurs after they have been added dynamically." Are you 100% sure that the elements are loaded before the event handlers are setup?

Comment: @RichardDalton. Yes following the logging the elemens are first added and then the eventhandlers are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event binding for dynamically added element can be done using `.on`, so
change

```
$(".infolnk").click(function ()
    { _getInfo($(this)); });
```

to

```
 $("table tr").on("click",".infolnk",function ()
    { _getInfo($(this)); });
```

Comment: Aha! Will try your option in an instant

Comment: as dynamically created elements are not available after `document.ready` and hence cannot bind events using `.click`. So jQuery provided `.on('click','selector',function(){...})` for binding events. For more information see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

Comment: Apparently your right. I always assumend (obviously wrongly) that `click` worked in the same way as `on` once the elements were loaded into the `DOM`. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing a tags

```
<a class="deletelnk" href="#"></a>
<a class="editlnk" href="#"></a>
<a class="infolnk" href="#">DRAFT</a>
```

Comment: The actual tags are closed. Something must have gone wrong during the copy from firebug.

Comment: then add &nbsp; inside these a tags, maybe they don't have width so you cannot click on them.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar was right. Dynamically added elements should be treated in another way then the one i used

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$(".deletelnk").click(function (){
    _delete($(this)); 
});

$(".infolnk").click(function (){
    _getInfo($(this)); 
});

function _delete(lnkClicked){
    alert("delete clicked");
}

function _getInfo(lnkClicked){
    alert("Info clicked");
}
```

Comment: Thats included inside another function. So I removed that extra function. Thats all

Comment: OP calls that function to add the event handlers to both.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry.. I didnt see that .ready() section. Thats why I answered like that.